# Can't read input file, IOException

Tags: java, image, file-io, ioexception

I'm trying to make the array of image buttons in a panel in Jform. For this i want to add the image by giving the path but here is the IO Exception that can't read input file. The error occurs as

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at serverui.ImageArray.main(ImageArray.java:38)
```

The code is as follow:
    package serverui;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageArray {
    Image[] images;

    public ImageArray(Image[] images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    private JPanel getContent() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2,5,5));
        panel.setBackground(Color.green.darker());
        for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(images[i]);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
            panel.add(label);
        }
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String prefix = "images/";
        String[] ids = { "desktopactive", "desktopoff" };
        String ext = ".png";
        Image[] images = new Image[ids.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            String path = prefix + ids[i] + ext;
            images[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        }

        ImageArray app = new ImageArray(images);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(app.getContent());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of concatenating strings to form filenames you should use `new File(parent, child).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follows, Issue in path

```
   String prefix = "D:\\TestFolder\\";
    String[] ids = { "Capture"};
    String ext = ".png";
    Image[] images = new Image[ids.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        String path = prefix + ids[i] + ext;
        images[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    }
```

In this way it is working for me. Some times if you provide a `prefix` as folder in `C` drive(operating system install partition), you may unable to read that file due to privileges issue. Else in above will solve your matter.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that both files exist.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        String path = prefix + ids[i] + ext;
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("file "+file+" does not exist");
        }
        images[i] = ImageIO.read(file);
    }
```

Make sure that `images` is relative to your current directory. If you put `images` in your classpath, you may use this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        String path = prefix + ids[i] + ext;
        URL url = ImageArray.class.getResource(path);
        if (url == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("url "+url+" does not exist");
        }
        images[i] = ImageIO.read(url);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on your platform, if this is indeed on windows. then you need to change it to \ on

```
String prefix = "images/"
```

What you can do though if you want is create an if statement that modifies the string based on the operating system.  The way you get what operating system you have is through

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```